# Why is CSS style not working?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a style for the HTML `<head>` tag. But it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css">
        home page
    </head>
</html>
```

And here is the css/style.css part:

```
#head {
    font-size: 15 px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
};
```

Comment: Why are you trying to style the head tag, which isn't rendered on screen?

Comment: `<head>` is different of `<header>`. Learn HTML basics

Comment: It isn't working after the removal of hash. Why should I remove the semicolons? Shouldn't there be semicolons between different properties.

Comment: @tonmoy71 The semicolon after the `}` is invalid.

Comment: `head` refers to the `head` element which is never rendered on teh page and so not styleable. `#head` referes to an element with an `id="head"`, which doesn't exist on your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you were aiming for, head is not rendered :-)

```css
header {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <header>
    home page
  </header>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have four problems.

1. The property is `color` not `font-color`
2. There shouldn't be a space between the number and unit part of a length
3. You are trying to target an element with `id="head"` but no such element exists in the document
4. The `head` element cannot include free text, so the parsing rules for HTML convert the document into this DOM:

.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        home page
    </body>
</html>
```

… so the content isn't in the `head` anyway:

You could style elements in the head if it was valid HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo title</title>
    <style>
        head { display: block; }
        head title { display: block; color: blue; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Demo heading</h1>
```

This is generally a poor idea though. You should use proper semantic HTML in the body for content you want to display in the main viewport.

You should also make use of an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) and a [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: Other errors in the OP's code are the `;` following the `}` in the css file (as mentioned in the comments), and the lack of a `<title>` element in the head, which is still obligatory.

Comment: And a big problem with this answer is that I honestly can't believe you are actually demonstrating to the OP how they should make content in the head visible! How could you? Yeah, I know, that's what they asked for, but come on! Oh, and if you want to make content in the head visible, please use a `<script type="text/plain">`, not the `<title>`. OK?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to modify the `head` tag. The `head` tag is hidden and contains information about the page like meta tags, the title, stylesheets, etc.

What you want to do is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css">
        <title>Home Page</title>

        <style>
            /* selecting the header tag*/
            header {
                font-size: 15 px;
                font-family: helvetica;
                color: blue;
                text-align: center;
            };

            /* Selecting the header id */
            #header {
                font-size: 15 px;
                font-family: helvetica;
                color: blue;
                text-align: center;
            };
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header id="header">
        This is the header
    </header>
    <div class="body-text">
    </div>
    <footer id="footer"></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a handy list of [30 CSS selectors](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048). The article says you need to memorize them but I still reference this blog all the time when using very specific selectors.